# Problem when use Spark SQL【2.1】 to work with PostgreSQL DB

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark

I use following test case to write data to a postgresql table, and it works fine.

`test("SparkSQLTest") {
    val session = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("SparkSQLTest").getOrCreate()
    val url = "jdbc:postgresql://dbhost:12345/db1"
    val table = "schema1.table1"
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("user", "user123")
    props.put("password", "pass@123")
    props.put(JDBCOptions.JDBC_DRIVER_CLASS, "org.postgresql.Driver")
    session.range(300, 400).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(url, table, props)
  }`

Then, I use following `spark-sql -f sql_script_file.sql` to write an hive data into postgresql table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW tmp_v1
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
OPTIONS (
  driver 'org.postgresql.Driver',
  url 'jdbc:postgresql://dbhost:12345/db1',
  dbtable 'schema1.table2',
  user 'user123',
  password 'pass@123',
  batchsize '2000'
);

insert into tmp_v1 select
name,
age
from test.person; ---test.person is the Hive db.table
```

But when I run the above script using `spark-sql -f sql_script.sql`, it complains that the postgresql user/passord is invalid, the exception is as follows, I think the above two methods are basically the same, so I would ask where the problem is, thanks.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: Invalid username/password,login denied.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:375)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:189)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:124)
at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:28)
at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:20)
at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:30)
at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:22)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:392)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:266)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:45)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:330)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CreateTempViewUsing.run(ddl.scala:76)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:75)
```